# Detect keys already pressed at the time script starts

Tags: linux, keyboard, shell-script

My script that runs in a Linux desktop environment (`XFCE`, `Gnome`) is registered to run on a global hot key event (e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). That script pastes something from the primary clipboard (I use `xclip` + `xdotool`) into the currently selected window edit box. The problem is paste fails because at that moment my hot keys are still pressed. My current solution is super ugly, I have the script sleep for 0.5 seconds - just enough to release the hot keys - before it executes paste command.

I need my script to wait until no key is pressed on the keyboard in order to run the main paste from clipboard logic.

I checked many related command line utilities like `xev`, `xinput`, `showkey`, etc. Though relevant they are of no use to me because they only start monitoring events when started. I need to fetch current state of keyboard keys whether something is already pressed at the time my script starts.

Any hint or pointer would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using `--clearmodifiers` with your `xdotool` commands.

Comment: I did. So far only the ugly delay helps

Answer (score 4):

`xinput query-state` can show presses keys. So your script can be like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while for did in $(xinput --list --id-only) ; do xinput query-state $did 2>/dev/null | grep down ; done | egrep -q . ; do sleep 0.1 ; done

xdotool type "$(xclip -o -selection primary)"
```

This will wait until **no** keys or buttons are pressed, so even mouse buttons count. But it works well enough for me.

Comment: This does not return for me, gives `unable to find device '2'` and '3' which are my Virtual core pointer / keyboard.